# stop a for loop, python

Tags: python, for-loop

I wrote some code using a for loop. Now I want to stop the for loop after it executed the loop one time. here is the for loop:

```
for table in tables: #reason for it to do it 12x

    for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
        firstTd = tr.find("td")
        if firstTd and firstTd.has_attr("class") and "indent" in firstTd['class']:
            values = {}
            tds = tr.find_all("td")
            maxVal = tds[1].find("span", class_="wx-value")
            avgVal = tds[2].find("span", class_="wx-value")
            minVal = tds[3].find("span", class_="wx-value")
            if maxVal:
                values['max'] = maxVal.text
            if avgVal:
                values['avg'] = avgVal.text
            if minVal:
                values['min'] = minVal.text
            if len(tds) > 4:
                sumVal = tds[4].find("span", class_="wx-value")
                if sumVal:
                    values['sum'] = sumVal.text
            scrapedData = {}
            scrapedData[firstTd.text] = values
            weatherdata.append(scrapedData)

with open ("january_2016.json", 'w' ) as outFile:
    json.dump(weatherdata, outFile, indent=2)
```

how do I do that?

Comment: If you don't want it to repeat at all, why is there a loop?

Answer (score 5):

Have a `break`:

```
for x in range(5):
    print x
    break
```

This prints `0` and stops execution.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the break command:

```
for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
    if any_condition_for_exit:
        break;
```

And would be fine, if you firstly read the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html).

It is really useful and is able to answer more of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by changing indentation.

**Case 1:**

```
for item in list:
   print(item)
   break
```

in case 1 , it will stop the execution as soon as print first item.

**Case 2:**

```
for item in list:
   print(item)
return
```

in case 2 , it will terminate naturally after printing all item. here Break is not needed because break is using for stop the execution force fully.

if you want to explore more , please go through this [link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/loops/for-while-and-nested-loops-in-python)